# Mutiple repositories checkout issue in Azure Devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

My code has multiple checkout's and when I run the pipeline, the directory path is not recognized for one of the checkout.

```
jobs:
- job: job1
  steps:
  - checkout: rep1
    path: test1
  - checkout: rep2
    path: test2

  - task: AzurePowerShell@5
    inputs:
      azureSubscription:xxxxx
      ScriptType: 'FilePath'
      ScriptPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/folder1/myPowershell.ps1'
      azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'
```

I see a warning which says "Module path not present as expected in hosted agent, skipping step to make module available". The Powershell script is never executed. Any help, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops&source=docs#checkout-path):

> If you have multiple checkout steps in your job, your source code is checked out into directories named after the repositories as a subfolder of `s` in `(Agent.BuildDirectory)`. If `(Agent.BuildDirectory)` is `C:\agent\_work\1` and your repositories are named `tools` and `code`, your code is checked out to `C:\agent\_work\1\s\tools` and `C:\agent\_work\1\s\code`.

So, it looks like the `ScriptPath` property of `AzurePowerShell@5` task in your pipeline should be built keeping this in mind. If the PowerShell file resides in `folder1` directory of the repository `rep1`, then the path should look like
`$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/rep1/folder1/myPowershell.ps1`.

Comment: Thank you very much, this solved my problem.